# Is it possible to find the last foundry sync date of a dataset from foundry code authoring?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I would like to programmatically determine whether the last sync date of a dataset is within a certain time frame, and I was wondering if it was possible to pull the last sync date as a column into a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in the foundry platform.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the schema definition of the synced dataset, you could add the Import Timestamp as column:

[image]

This will add an additional column to your dataset containing the timestamp when the sync finished:

[image]